# How to configure for singleton - Queue Triggered Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I'd like an azure function that's triggered from an Azure storage account queue to run as a singleton.

The function app is in-process and net6:

```
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

My function currently looks as follows:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(QueueTrigger))]    
[Singleton(Mode = SingletonMode.Listener)]
public async Task QueueBatch([QueueTrigger("TriggerSurvey")] TriggerMsg triggerMsg)
```

Following the suggestion from @Moho I added the following to the host.json and the Singleton method decorator as now shown above but this made no difference to the behaviour of the app.

```
"extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
      "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:30",
      "batchSize": 1,
      "maxDequeueCount": 5,
      "newBatchThreshold": 8,
      "messageEncoding": "base64"
    }
  }
```

I tested as follows:
I published a message to the queue. The function consumed this and began its work - writing to Azure Sql. This job took approx 3 minutes and it inserted a log table many times as it worked, along with a correlation id for the function instance. After a few seconds of publishing the first message I published a second. From the log table I could see that a different function instance had consumed and was processing concurrently with the first.

Anyone know how to configure so that only one instance of the function will ever poll the queue?

Comment: Can you check your function has any error during process first message?

Comment: No errors, it completed successfully

Comment: I think this is specific scenario based on your code, after job completed how many correlation ids is in table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The batch size and the threshold for getting a new batch are
> configurable in the host.json file. If you want to minimize parallel
> execution for queue-triggered functions in a function app, you can set
> the batch size to 1. This setting eliminates concurrency only so long
> as your function app runs on a single virtual machine (VM).

```
host.json > extensions > queues > batchSize
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=csharp

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think your suggestion combined with [Singleton(Mode = SingletonMode.Listener)] attribute on the function should work https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#singletonmodelistener

Comment: I'm afraid this did not work - please see edits in question

Comment: @RobBowman what behavior are you witnessing to lead you to believe the Microsoft-documented settings and `SingletonAttribute` aren't working?  What is it you're trying to accomplish, specifically?

Comment: please see addition to the question. I have now worked around this problem by setting a "being processed" flag in the Azure Sql DB. So now the first thing the function does is check the status of the flag and only continues if false.

Comment: came back to this today and replaced the entry for host.json - then it started working